# ASP.NET Dockerfile for different environments

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ARG ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OrderAPI.dll"]
```

All I want to do is when during **build** I can specify the environment. Right now I am able to build and then run in a specific environment using -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT but I want the build to be done in a specific environment.

When I look at how others have done it using shell scripts etc. Is there a simpler way to do it within the Dockerfile. For my other dockerfiles I just pass in the arguments but unsure with appsettings.

I've added

```
ARG ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}
```

But running the below still runs in production (of course i can change it in the dockerfile but don't want to do that)

```
docker build --build-arg ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -t order-api:latest .
```

Comment: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT mainly affects the application when it runs, not the build.

Comment: I see, I'm building a CI/CD pipeline so then I'd just change it during the deployment when running or create two dockerfiles

Comment: Where in your Dockerfile have you placed the ARG and ENV statements?

Comment: You can put your long environments settings on docker compose yaml file. Then run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` commands. See [this link](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-compose-aspnet-core/) which makes use of docker compose in asp.net core.

Comment: @HansKilian I've edited the post

Comment: @yogihosting yep docker-compose would likely work as opposed to a single Dockerfile. Just want to see if it can be done through a dockerfile itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ENV statement is in the build part of the Dockerfile, so it's not included in the final image. The stages in a Dockerfile are very separate and pretty much nothing carries over from one stage to the next.

Move it to the final part and it should be set when you run the container.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
ARG ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OrderAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks that works now! Is this good practice, just thinking about the other comment in the post about “ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT mainly affects the application when it runs, not the build”. Or shall we assume they  misinterpreted the question